# How to swap between functions implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to swap between two functions implementation in C++ ?

Something like this:

```
void printA(); // print a char
void printB(); // print b char

printA(); // output: a
printB(); // output: b

functionSwap(printA, printB);

printA(); // output: b
printB(); // output: a
```

I want to use it with the `ExitProcess` function.

Comment: This seems to be a possible instance of the XY problem. What is the root goal you're trying to achieve by swapping `ExitProcess`?

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov I am participating in some kind of competition in which everyone want to make the enemy process stop and there is the option of using DLL injection and using the ExitProcess function in order to make my process exit so I want to avoid the option of others to use the function in my process.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can bind a pointer to both functions in two variables and swap those.

```
void (*f1)() = printA;
void (*f2)() = printB;

f1(); // output: a
f2(); // output: b

std::swap(f1, f2);

f1(); // output: b
f2(); // output: a
```

Comment: @hellow no. `std::function` is a heavywieght type-erased container for callable objects. If a function pointer is enough, use that.

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap them in objects (or pointers to functions):

```
std::function<void()> myprintA = printA;
std::function<void()> myprintB = printB;

std::swap(myprintA, myprintB);

myprintA();
myprintB();
```

Otherwise, you are working with symbols themselves, and you can't swap this.